# Is it possible to treat $\partial$ as an operator?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I recently discovered that I can treat $d$ as an operator, and $dz$ as a certain variable defined as the infinitesimal change of $z$ for any variable $z$, and it is always defined with proportion to other variables $\left(\text{e.g.}  \, \frac{dz}{dx} \right)$, and that's how we use it in integrating, and that's how I can get some sense into why the fundamental theorem of calculus is true.

For example $z=x^2$ we have that $dz=2x\,dx$

and if $f=x^2+y^2$, we have that $df=2x \,dx + 2y \, dy$ by  partial differentiation. Now, I noticed that
$$y=x^2\implies dy=2x \,dx\implies d^2y=d(2x \, dx) = 2x\,d^2x+2(dx)^2$$
Here, I treated $d$ as an operator and $dx$ and $x$ as two separate  variables, and I used $d^2y=d(dy)=d(2x \, dx)$ and I used partial differentiation, again assuming that $dx$ and $x$ are two separate variables. Similarly, we can have
$$f=x^2+y^2\implies df=2x\,dx+2y\,dy \implies d^2f = 2 (dx)^2 + 2x \,d^2 x + 2(dy)^2+2y\,d^2y$$
This is also consistent with $\displaystyle \frac{d^2f}{(dx)^2} = 2+2\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+2y\cdot\frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2}$

Note that this is consistent with the second derivative of $y$, we have that $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2}=2$ and from our last conclusion
$$\frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2}=2x\,\frac{d^2x}{(dx)^2}+2\cdot\frac{(dx)^2}{(dx)^2}$$
and since $\displaystyle \frac{d^2x}{(dx)^2}=\frac{d^2}{(dx)^2}x=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}x\right)=0$, the above equation simplifies to $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2}=2$, consistent with our previous definitions.

I know that this is not a rigorous definition of something existing in Math (or may be it is and I'm not aware), but I sometimes use this and assume it somehow exists in Math.

Now, I tried to do similar things with the operator $\partial$, and I found inconsistencies. Is there a way to define $\partial$ as an operator and $\partial z$ as a variable the same way, and treat them with the same level of comfort I had while I treated $d$ here?

I haven't taken real analysis yet, but I'd still appreciate it if someone posted an answer based on real analysis with some preliminary explanation.

Comment: $d$ is not an operator as an "infinitesimal change" is not a well-defined mathematical notion. What is true is that the derivative is a linear operator in a space of differentiable functions. However, given a Riemannian manifold, there is a well-defined linear map $f\mapsto df$ from a space of smooth functions over the manifold and the corresponding differential, and this $df$ is mathematically well-defined

Comment: Infinitesimal change is perfectly well-defined in hyperreal numbers.

Comment: @johnnyb That is not the setting for most of mathematics, especially not differential geometry.

Comment: Guys, I've only just finished a Calculus textbook, so I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: Basically, $dx$ is an infinitesimal change - an infinitely small change in the value of $x$.  Cameron was complaining that "infinitesimal" is not well-defined in mathematics, but, in fact, it has been since the 1960s.  It is true that most people define calculus in the "real numbers", but hyperreal numbers (numbers that include infinities and infinitesimals) are a straightforward extension, just as the complex numbers are a straightforward extension.  It doesn't do any damage to existing numbers, it only extends them to allow for infinitesimals.

Comment: Therefore, if someone is dealing in infinitesimals, it makes perfect sense to change the context to hyperreal numbers, just as if someone were to speak of imaginary numbers, it would make perfect sense to change the context to complex numbers.  Since the primary change that hyperreal numbers brought about was to put infinitesimals and infinities on the number line in a way that matches up with what we already do with real numbers, I don't see how that is a stretch.

Comment: One other note @AnasA.Ibrahim - on the second derivative, the form you give above (which is the common form) is not algebraically manipulable.  An algebraically manipulable form is $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$.  This is the quotient rule applied to $\frac{dy}{dx}$.  This is not currently taught in many books, but may help reduce confusion in the future.  You can also see my paper "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials" or my book "Calculus from the Ground Up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get inconsistencies using $\partial$ is that in the fraction $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ there is information about the numerator in the denominator, so, when you split the fraction, you lose information.

A more straightforward notation, which does allow splitting the fraction, is to notate on the partial differential which variables were allowed to change.  So, for instance, a better notation would be:

$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial_x y}{dx}$$

The right-hand side is a more precise notation.  You can get at most of the truths of partial derivatives by saying, if you have a function $f()$ of variables $x$, $y$, and $z$, then:

$$ df = \partial_x f + \partial_y f + \partial_z f$$

In other words, the total infinitesimal change in $f$ (i.e., $df$) is equal to the sum of the infinitesimal changes due to each individual variable.

Once you see this, then the other rules are just basic algebraic manipulations from this.

Example: the chain rule.  Let's say we wanted to know $\frac{df}{dt}$.  we get this by dividing both sides by $dt$:

$$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial_x f}{dt} + \frac{\partial_y f}{dt} + \frac{\partial_z f}{dt} $$

Now multiply each term on the right by a variation of "1" that matches the partial.

$$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial_x f}{dt}\frac{dx}{dx} + \frac{\partial_y f}{dt}\frac{dy}{dy} + \frac{\partial_z f}{dt}\frac{dz}{dz} $$

Now, swap the denominators of the right-hand side.

$$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial_x f}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial_y f}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial_z f}{dz}\frac{dz}{dt} $$

Written in the typical notation, this becomes:

$$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt} $$

Comment: The fundamental problem I have with this approach is: if $dx$ is an infinitesimal, **which one** is it? Suppose $f$ is a function of $x$ such that $df/dx = 2$ when $x = 0.$ We can say that $dx$ is an infinitesimal obtained somehow by applying an operator $d$ to $x,$ and $df$ is an infinitesimal obtained somehow by applying an operator $d$ to $f,$ and we somehow find that $df = 2 dx,$ that is, the infinitesimal obtained by applying the operator $d$ is twice as large in one case than in the other; but how did that operator "know" to make $df$ twice as large as $dx$?

Comment: @DavidK - why do you need to know which one?  Infinitely zoomed in, smooth and continuous functions are basically linear at each particular point.  Therefore, it doesn't really matter which infinitesimal you choose, the relative behavior is the same.

Comment: @david in an hyperreal setting $dx$ is any positive infinitesimal number, it doesn't matter which of them

Comment: **How** does the operator $d$ ensure the relative behavior is the same, thought? I'm sure some sense can be made out of the fact that $df = 2dx,$ but it seems it would require a lot more than just saying $dx$ and $df$ are infinitesimals. And if you actually go to the trouble to rigorously define the hyperreals, by the time you're done I'm not sure it would be simpler than the "linear map on smooth functions over a Riemannian manifold" approach. Besides, didn't Robinson prove they are equivalent?

Comment: I can understand something like $f'(x)$ as the real part of $(f(x+o)-f(x))/o$ where $o$ is an infinitesimal (it doesn't really matter which one, I'm fine with that), where we are literally evaluating the ratio as it is and not taking a limit. But there is still the same symbol $o$ on both top and bottom of this ratio.

Comment: @Masacroso Fair point, in a derivative as a ratio of infinitesimals it really doesn't matter what's in the denominator as long as the numerator follows in the correct ratio. It's the mechanics of enforcing that ratio by applying the operator $d$ to different variables that puzzles me.

Comment: @DavidK - the way I think about it is this.  Imagine that there is a fundamental variable, $q$, that all other variables depend on, but which is never present in the equation.  The $d()$ operator evaluates its expression at $q = q_0$ and $q = q_0 + \epsilon$.  Because $d()$ is in terms of this unstated variable $q$, all of the $d()$ operators sync up.

Comment: So in that interpretation, if I understand you, $\epsilon$ serves the same role as the particular infinitesimal $o$ that I used in $(f(x+o)-f(x))/o$. We don't actually care which infinitesimal it is, we just care that it is an infinitesimal and that we use the same infinitesimal every time we apply the $d$ operator. And I agree that this would ensure $df = 2 dx$ when $f'(x) = 2.$

Comment: @DavidK but $o$ cannot be zero (zero is an infinitesimal)

Comment: That resolves a question that's been bugging me (intermittently) for more than a quarter century. It was definitely worth reading this answer!